# ReactJS: How to wrap react-select in redux-form field?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-bootstrap, react-select

I am working on `react-select` library and facing some issues, I am using `redux-form` library and importing `<Field />` component from it. So that I can submit the values via form to service.

Below mentioned code works fine, when I use default `<Select>` from react-select. I can able to select the values from the drop down and the value will be selected even on focus out the value will remain. But selected value is not submitting via form due to `redux-form` that's why I am wrapping `<Select />` component and using with `<Field name="sample" component={RenderSelectInput} id="sampleEX" options={options} />`

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import RenderSelectInput from './RenderSelectInput'; // my customize select box

var options = [{ value: 'one', label: 'One' }, { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }];


class SelectEx extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { selectValue: 'sample' }
        this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
    }

    updateValue(newValue) {
        this.setState({ selectValue: newValue })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Select name="select1" id="selectBox" value={this.state.selectValue} options={options} onChange={this.updateValue}/>

                //This works but value won't submit ...

                <Field name="sample" component={RenderSelectInput} id="sampleEX" options={options} />
            //For this, selected value vanishes once I come out of component. 
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SelectEx;
```

But when I use with my **customized select** (I am wrapping the  to submit the value from form) the `<Select>` component can be visible in UI even the values also. But unable to select the value from dropdown ..., If I select also it displays in the `<Select>` box but on focus out it vanishes. Please help me ...

**RenderSelectInput** component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';


const RenderSelectInput = ({input, options, name, id}) => (

    <div>
        <Select {...input} name={name} options={options} id={id} />
    </div>
)

export default RenderSelectInput;
```

Answer (score 11):

When using `react-select` with redux-form, you'll need to change the default behavior of `onChange` and `onBlur` method and call `redux-form`'s `onChange` and `onBlur` method respectively.

So, Try this:

```
const RenderSelectInput = ({input, options, name, id}) => (
    <Select 
         {...input}
         id={id} 
         name={name} 
         options={options}
         value={input.value}
         onChange={(value) => input.onChange(value)}
         onBlur={(value) => input.onBlur(value)}
    />
)
```

and use the above component like

```
<Field component={RenderSelectInput} />
```

Calling `redux-form`'s `onBlur` method when focus is removed from the `Select` field will prevent loss of value.

Comment: Hi, The above mentioned solution did not resolve my problem, I am seeing same behavior. I can able to select values from dropdown list but the value vanishes when I click outside. You have mentioned `onChange` in `RenderSelectInput` component but not in `<Field />`  is this causing issue ? or 'value' is not mentioned in either `RenderSelectInput` or `Field` component ..

Comment: Which version of `react-select` are you using?

Comment: Have you specified `onBlur` function, as I said in the answer?

Comment: I am using `New version 1.0.0-rc` which is available now in GitHub.com.

Comment: yes I used `onBlur` function as you mentioned in `RenderSelectInput` component. I just made changes as you suggested and checked, it didn't work. Is there any issue with value like we are not mentioning `value={this.state.selectValue}` at `redux-form`'s `<Field  />` component in `SelectEx` component (My 1st .js file mentioned above)

Comment: I've updated my answer. I forgot to add value for `Select`. Now, it should work.

Comment: I updated the component `RenderSelectInput` with `value={input.value}` still it is not working. Please tell me the `redux` component which I am using now it is `<Field component={RenderSelectInput} />`  Do I need to add anything to this component ?

Comment: It's working fine for me. Can you post your whole code which can reproduce the problem you are facing? Are you using it with `multi={true}`?

Comment: probably a little late, but I am facing now the same problem and solved it calling `input.onBlur` without arguments: `onBlur={() => input.onBlur()}`. Apparently, the `onBlur` method of `Select` receives an event and `input.value` is an empty string and calling `input.onBlur` with any of those values dispatches the BLUR action with `payload = ''` which empties the value of the field in the redux state

Answer (score 3):

Here this worked for me,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

export default class RenderSelectInput extends Component {
 onChange(event) {
  if (this.props.input.onChange && event != null) {
   this.props.input.onChange(event.value);
  } else {
   this.props.input.onChange(null);
  }
 }

 render() {
  const { input, options, name, id, ...custom } = this.props;
  return (
   <Select
    {...input}
    {...custom}
    id={id}
    name={name}
    options={options}
    value={this.props.input.value || ''}
    onBlur={() => this.props.input.onBlur(this.props.input.value)}
    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
   />
  );
 }
}
```

this was extracted from here: https://ashiknesin.com/blog/use-react-select-within-redux-form/

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Just a minor change to support multi={true}. In onChange use:       if (event.value) {
        this.props.input.onChange(event.value);
      }
      else {
        this.props.input.onChange(event);
      }

Answer (score 2):

Use this which works perfectly and it also handles redux form validation.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import {FormGroup} from "reactstrap";


class CustomSelect extends Component {

 render() {
   const {meta: {touched, error}} = this.props;
   const className = ` form-group mb-3 ${touched && error ? 'has-danger' : '' }`;
   return (    
        <FormGroup>
                <Select
                      {...this.props}
                       value={this.props.input.value}
                       onChange={(value) => this.props.input.onChange(value)}
                       onBlur={() => this.props.input.onBlur(this.props.input.value)}
                       options={this.props.options}
                       placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                    />
                    <div className={className}>
                         <div className="text-help">
                              {touched ? error : ''}
                          </div>
                     </div>
           </FormGroup>

            );
```

Use the CustomSelect component in redux form field component as

```
   <Field
        name='country_name'
        options={this.state.countries}
        component={CustomSelect}
        placeholder="Select your country"
   />
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to call the **onBlur** without any argument. The issue with Hardik's answer was, it was not working in iPad (May be also in other iOS or touch devices. I was unable to check).

The onBlur event is automatically triggered along with the onChange event in iPad. It caused the select value to reset to its initial value. So I had to call onBlur method like this,

onBlur={(value) => input.onBlur()}

```
const RenderSelectInput = ({input, options, name, id}) => (
    <Select 
         {...input}
         id={id} 
         name={name} 
         options={options}
         value={input.value}
         onChange={(value) => input.onChange(value)}
         onBlur={(value) => input.onBlur()}
    />
)
```

and used as,

```
<Field component={RenderSelectInput} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `onBlurResetInput` property to false.

Something like.

```
const SelectInput = ({input: { onChange, value }, options, name, id}) => (
    <Select              
      name={name}
      value={value} 
      options={options}
      onChange={onChange}
      onBlurResetsInput={false}
    />
)
```

Hope this helps!